# perl regex to get trailing numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to basically trying to separate a specific amount of text from the one or more numbers that appear at the end. The below works when there is 1 trailing number but not when there is two or more? Shouldn't the (\d+) be getting the "12" in "P_TIME12"?

```
my @strs = ('P_ABC1','P_DFRES3','P_TIME12');
foreach my $str (@strs) {
        if ($str =~ /^P_(\w+)(\d+)$/) {
                print "word " . $1 . " digits " . $2 . "\n";
        }
}
```

Results in

```
word ABC digits 1
word DFRES digits 3
word TIME1 digits 2
```

TIA

Comment: Use `\pL` to match letters, not `\w`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\w matches "word characters", including digits and underscore. Because you've asked for at least one digit (\d+), \w is being greedy and matching one as well.

You should be more explicit than `\w`, and use `/^P_([A-Za-z_]+)(\d+)$/` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` contains digits, use `[_a-zA-Z]` instead, if the only digits are at the end

and `\w+` is greedy, it will first match the whole word and leaves nothing for `\d+`, so it has to backtrack 1 character and the last character is good enought for `\d+`

if you want lazy operator, because you have digits in the middle, use `^P_(\w+?)(\d+)$`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^P_(\D+)(\d+)$/
```

The character class `\d` matches digits; its negation `\D` matches everything else.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is acceptable for you to capture also spaces in the *first part*, a simpler solution is to match anything *ungreedily* before the trailing numbers, then the trailing numbers *greedily*.

This has the advantage that you can match even digits in the first part (provided that they don't appear at the end).
And spaces as well, as already said.

That is:

```perl
my @strs = qw(P_1ABC1 P_DFRES3 P_3TIME12);
foreach (@strs) {
    if ( /^P_(.*?)(\d+)$/ ) {
        print ">$1<", "\t\t", ">$2<", "\n"
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
>1ABC<      >1<
>DFRES<     >3<
>3TIME<     >12<
```